# Can't find any entries in non-empty MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;   

var UsersCoursesSchema = new Schema({
      _User: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
      },
      _Course: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Courses'
      }
    });
```

And this document in **MongoDB**:

[image]

But when I try to run this query, I get an empty array as a result:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UsersCourses = mongoose.model('UsersCourses');

exports.getUserCourses = function(req, res) {
    UsersCourses.find({}, function(err, userCourses) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(userCourses);

    });
};
```

Why?

Comment: why using "new" in the query ?

Comment: I saw it that way somewhere else. And also I implemented an another GET, just on a different table, but with the same syntax as here... and it works.

Comment: I got some new information, I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your _userId key inside double quotes and removing new as follows:

```
exports.getUserCourses = function(req, res) {
UserCourses.find({"_User": ObjectId("5bef2b759d8e490944af9e96")}, function(err, userCourses) {
    });
};
```

also try with this shortcut:

```
exports.getUserCourses = function(req, res) {
UserCourses.find(ObjectId("5bef2b759d8e490944af9e96"), function(err, userCourses) {
    });
};
```

this should works.

Comment: I updated the original post because my issue isn't derived from the query filter parameters, but from somewhere else.